# Is there an API or library available to integrate an ERC20 compatible wallet into my android app?

Tags: wallets, tokens, erc-20, ico, android

If the android app being developed is going to display balances and allow sending and receiving of ERC20 tokens, is there an API or library that people would recommend for this functionality?